# Publish CPython package to PyPI with pre-built bdists for platforms

Tags: python, c++, c, go, pypi

I have a Go package that I'd like to serve as a Python package. I can compile the Go code into a C/C++ extension for Python as a `.so` dynamic library. I've successfully loaded and used that package locally with Python. Now I'd like to publish to PyPI.

How can I publish to PyPI when I have only binary distributions (bdists)? The Go compiler allows me to compile for any platform (Windows, Linux, MacOS, BSD, ...) luckily, but how can I include all these wheels in the `setup.py`? I do not have any `.py` file in the package, and you can ignore the Go part by thinking that this is a pure C/C++ extension without Python code compiled in to dynamic library.

How should my `setup.py` look like? Is it possible to release without a source distribution (sdist)?

EDIT: I could decouple the Go and C part by building a dynamic library and C header file from Go, and then continue as would any C extension for Python by building it with `gcc`, linking against the dynamic library of Go, and creating a dynamic library of the Python package ready to be imported.